# How to remove primary constraint in a Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I had a migration with the following constraint:

`$table->uuid('id')->primary();`

is it possible to remove this `primary()` constraint in a following migration? I tried this:

`$table->uuid('id')->change();`

but it doesn't work. What's the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->dropPrimary( 'id' );
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#dropping-indexes

Answer (score 1):

try [dropPrimary](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_dropPrimary) method :

```
  $table->dropPrimary('id');
```

this will drop only the key constraint not the column